# Ionic: Unable to get different data from $http post method

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.    Currently i am working on login functionality using web-service, its working fine.    I am saving login information using `sessionStorage`.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('loggedin_id', data.uid);
```

after that redirect to profile page using `$state.go('app.profile', {}, { reload: true });`.   In profile controller fetching information on the basis of `loggedin_id` using `$http.post` method.

At first time i am getting logged in user's detail on profile page, when i logout using `sessionStorage.clear();` it redirect back to login page and than i am logged in again  with another user and redirected to profile page it will not display current logged in user's detail it display old user's detail.

I have tried to alert `loggedin_id` within login function it alert's correct id of users but not user's information. Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you getting correct response from API ?

Comment: Yes, i am getting correct response from API

Comment: try using $scope.$apply(); after you are assigning the response to scope variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this by using `loggedin_id` as  `$stateParams` in profile route.   Redirect after login like

```
$state.go('app.profile', {userID:sessionStorage.getItem('loggedin_id')},{location: "replace", reload: true});
```

At profile controller post userID as parameter of API.   Now i am able to get proper information of logged in user.